# Do proficiencies with one thing from multiple different sources stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, proficiency, stacking

In D&D 5e it is possible for a character to receive proficiency in the same skill, tool, weapon and/or armor more than once via Class, Race, and/or Background.

Do any of these proficiencies stack, thereby allowing a character to receive their proficiency bonus more than once?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## No, proficiency bonuses never stack

> Your proficiency bonus can’t be added to a single die
> roll or other number more than once. - D&D Basic Rules V0.1 Chapter 1, P. 7

You can only ever receive a proficiency bonus once regardless of how many sources grant you proficiency in it. When picking skill and tool proficiencies granted by a background or class, Players should try to avoid overlapping proficiencies as the benefits are nil

### However a proficiency bonus may be increased or decreased based on circumstances

> Occasionally, your
> proficiency bonus might be modified (doubled or halved,
> for example) before you apply it. If a circumstance
> suggests that your proficiency bonus applies more than
> once to the same roll or that it should be multiplied
> more than once, you nevertheless add it only once,
> multiply it only once, and halve it only once. - D&D Basic Rules V0.1 Chapter 1, P. 7

DMs can use this as a way to give a bonus to skill checks based on good roleplay and/or planning.

### The Rogue's Expertise feature is an exception

> **Expertise**
> At 1st level, choose two of your skill proficiencies, or
> one of your skill proficiencies and your proficiency with
> thieves’ tools. Your proficiency bonus is doubled for any
> ability check you make that uses either of the chosen
> proficiencies.
> At 6th level, you can choose two more of your
> proficiencies. - D&D Basic Rules V0.1 Chapter 3, P. 27

While not allowing proficiency bonuses to be counted more than once, expertise allows a Rogue to double the benefit of their proficiency bonus to two skills (or thieves' tools) at level 1 and again at level 6.

### Backgrounds granting a redundant proficiency let you pick a different proficiency instead

In the Backgrounds section of the Basic Rules & PHB, the following rule [is listed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#Proficiencies):

> If a character would gain the same proficiency from two different sources, he or she can choose a different proficiency of the same kind (skill or tool) instead.

(Note that, while unclear, this rule [may *only* apply](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/125024/15614) to background proficiencies.)

[Custom backgrounds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#CustomizingaBackground) are also an option available to players to avoid duplicate proficiencies due to backgrounds.

Comment: Is expertise really an exception? It seems to be covered by rules paragraph 2. Sounds more like an example.

Comment: @GMNoob I see it as an exception because its always-on not via DM Fiat/by circumstance.

Comment: Also add bardic expertise. Expertise is a feature of skill monkeys, to name them very effective at what they do.