# How does the attack proficiency bonus stack with multiple sets of weapons training?

Tags: dnd-5e, proficiency, drow

I am creating a drow ranger. They're at 3rd level, and it's my first time playing.

Their attack score is proficiency + ability + other bonuses.

They have Drow weapon training which includes shortswords, rapiers, and hand crossbows. My ranger class gives me simple & martial weapons training.

Does that mean their attack score is (2+2) + ability + other bonuses?
[image]

Comment: 3rd level, jumping into a game.  first time playing.

Comment: I've given this question a small revision. Can you check & make sure it's still saying what you're asking about? You can edit it further if you like, and you can access the previous version by clicking the "edited X time ago" link at the bottom center of your post.

Comment: the heck is a dupe?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to Welcome you to RPG.SE.  I see you've taken the tour. I hope you'll browse some of our other questions and answers as you begin to enjoy the game.  While I suggest that this may be a duplicate of the question I linked to, that's not a foul or anything. There are as of this writing 23,899 questions on this site. (PS thanks for the character sheet info, helped in making the answer fit your needs).

Comment: Since we occasionally get multiple questions about the same thing, we prefer to consolidate them together pointing to the single clearest (or oldest) question of the bunch. This is hopefully a good thing for you since you'll already have an answer or solution available from the earlier question. If those answers don't cover your question, we generally ask that you show us what's different so we can better figure out how to solve your specific case. You're not in trouble for posting a duplicate, this isn't counted against you in any way. I've marked this one a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [Training proficiencies don't stack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44243/22566).

It means 4+2 (ability and proficiency) as your ability is 18 for a rapier, or a hand crossbow, or a long bow, or a short sword. There are no other bonuses unless you left some out in your question.

The overlap between Drow and Ranger proficiency in weapons does not add / stack proficiency.

If you had made a Drow wizard, the wizard would have the same race based weapon proficiencies -- short swords, rapiers, hand crossbows -- which is a good deal since a normal wizard does not.

Comment: thank you, my DM is in Chicago, i am on the west coast.  he has been as helpful as he can, but the time difference makes it hard to communicate.

Comment: @ShadyGrin Glad to be of help.  My DM is in Spokane, two of us are on Central time, the other three on Eastern time. (Yeah, tough to get it all sorted sometimes ...)

Answer (score 3):

No, not 2 + 2. Proficiency bonuses don't stack even if you get them from multiple sources. You either know it or you don't. So assuming +2 as your proficiency bonus and, say, +3 as your Dex or Str, and no magic weapons or other non-proficiency bonuses, add 5 to the d20 roll.